# WP_Query Meta_key is text value and need to sort as numeric not working

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I have the following code below in my ~WP_Query`.

```
$args[ 'meta_key'] = 'price';
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value meta_value_num';
$args['order'] = 'ASC';
```

The custom field in question has historic data that was created in a custom field and set as text. When I run my query I get the following results:

> 1,199.00, 1,299.99 169.99, 379.95.

which looks like a correct alpha sort. However, the higher numbers should appear last and the lower values first. I have tried to adjust the custom field to numeric, however I lose the custom field data.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I should either rewrite my query or transfer my text custom field data to numeric data?

Answer (score 2):

A `meta_value` field is *always* text; the fieldtype in the database structure is `longtext`, so unless you're explicitly typecasting when retrieving it (i.e. `$price = (float)$custom['price'][0];` - which won't help with ordering in the first place), you can't 'adjust' the custom field data - it's always stored as text.

Having said that, you should simply remove the initial `meta_value` in your `orderby` argument:

```
$args['meta_key'] = 'price';
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$args['order'] = 'ASC';
```

Having used this exact argument set myself just yesterday, it works perfectly.

Comment: Very neat minimalistic solution!!!